# Date_format não funciona em codigo

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Depois de seguir varias instruções e guias de funcionamento do Date_format, preferi pedir ajuda, pois tentei tudo e não consegui formatar a saída da data e hora do banco de dados Mysql.
Alguém sabe o porque desta função não funcionar neste código?
eu preciso da hora na saída 29/02/2006 20:20.
Na minha tabela a minha linha data esta do tipo datetime.

```
<?php 
        // aqui inicia a busca de comentarios dentro do banco de dados.

        require 'conexao.php';

            $buscaComentario = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE identificacao = '1' AND moderacao ='nao' ORDER BY data DESC ");

                while ($lista = mysql_fetch_array($buscaComentario)) {


                    $nome =         $lista['nome'];
                    $site =         $lista['site'];
                    $comentario =   $lista['comentario'];
                    $avatar =       $lista['avatar'];
                    $data =         $lista['data'];


                    DATE_FORMAT('data','%d/%c/%Y %H:%i:%s');
                    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_paulo');



                    echo "
                        <div id='comentario'>
                            <img src='uploads/$avatar' width='80'></img>        
                            <p><strong> $nome</strong></p>
                            <p>$comentario $site </p>
                            <span><strong> $data</strong></span>
                        </div>

                        ";
        }
        ?>
    <hr/>
    <?php
```

Comment: Você está confundindo as coisas. O `date_format` do `mysql` é uma coisa, a do `php` é outra.

Comment: obrigado colega, o que devo usar neste caso entao para conseguir buscar uma data no banco de dados do jeito que eu preciso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe um erro no seu código.

Você está tentando formatar a data pelo php, observando o seu código, mas pela sua intenção percebo que quer formatar pelo `Mysql`.

Então altere esse trecho da sua query para:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(data, 'd/m/Y') AS data_formatada FROM comentarios
```

Assim, basta utilizar `$lista['data_formatada']` para acessar a data formatada

Comment: entendi entao o porque, so me falta acertas esta chamada, tive um erro logo apos a chama, esta certo fazer assim?
    $buscaComentario = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE identificacao = '1' AND moderacao ='nao' ORDER BY data DESC ");

    $buscaComentario .= mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(data, 'd/m/Y') AS data_formatada FROM comentarios");

Comment: tive erro a seguir a este codigo que postei
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Answer (score 2):

O problema é na função mysql_fetch_array(), ela recebe dois parâmetros, a primeira é a variavel que recebeu o resultado da sua query, e o segundo o tipo de array a ser retornado. Tente assim:

```
mysql_fetch_array($buscaComentario, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Basicamente retorna um array associativo, [veja mais aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Com relação ao formato da hora, você quer no formato dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm, similar a resposta anterior adicione apenas:

`SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(data, 'd/m/Y H:i') AS data_formatada FROM comentarios`

Veja uma referencia completa da função [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

A razão que eu imagino pela você está sendo negativado (não tenho certeza) é por estar usando a extensão **MYSQL** para manipulação de bases de dados mysql. Uma vez que ela está em desuso, já que existem outras opões como **mysqli** e **pdo**. Além disso a extensão MYSQL foi removida da versão 7 do PHP. Então seria aconselhável você migrar para mysqli (funções similares a MYSQL). Um breve [tutorial](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/guia-pratico-de-mysqli-no-php).